# Draw square with center point and size

Tags: c#, vb.net

Example:
I want to draw a square with the center in point (10,10) and the edge 20.

How is this possible using Graphics.DrawRectangle ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You don't understand my question or what?

Comment: It's possible by using the correct overload and passing the correct parameters to it.  You'll need to perform a few calculations first to work out where the top left of the rectangle is relative to the centre point you want.

Comment: Can you show [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), please? We will try to solve the problems you face, not to code for you.

Comment: It's ridiculous to close this question as anclear. He wants to draw a square given the center and the size. What the hell you don't understand? Come on guys...

Comment: No it is __not__ possible. You __could__ draw a square around a center point with an __odd__ side length, though. If you have a problem, feel free to ask. The way to do it is by showing us the code you have. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No overload of Graphics.DrawRectangle takes the center point as a parameter and draws a rectangle around it. see this

I think you can create you own function for the same like below:

```
public void DrawRectangle(Pen pen, int xCenter, int yCenter, int width, int height)
{
    //Find the x-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw.
    int x = xCenter - width / 2;

    //Find y-coordinate of the upper-left corner of the rectangle to draw. 
    int y = yCenter - height / 2;

    Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, width, height);
}
```

Comment: You get my upvote if you provide this as an extension method for the `Graphics` class :)

Comment: This code gives a StackOverflow excpetion: when you call `DrawRectangle()` in the method you have to do it on Graphics. Still prefer an extension method.

Comment: @Fuex has a point - you're calling the routine recursively!

Comment: Guys I didn't created an extension method because `Graphics` class already have an overload with same set of parameters. The only thing I forgot is to qualify the `DrawRectangle` method when I am calling it, that's why it is being called recursively. Here I we are not supposed to call the same method which I implemented, but the method from `Graphics` class. Apologies for the mistake, I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1-Just displace the drawing. If you want to draw a 20x20 pixels with center at 10,10 then draw it at 0,0 (Center - Size / 2)

2-Use the TranslateTransform function to displace the Graphics origin to -Size / 2

If you use the second approach remember to reset your transform after drawing, but I recommend to use the first option.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extension method:

```
public static class Utilities{
    public static void DrawSquare(this Graphics g, Point center, int edgeSize, Pen pen){
        int halfEdge = edgeSize/2;
        Rectangle square = new Rectangle(center.X - halfEdge, center.Y - halfEdge, edgeSize, edgeSize);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, square);
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
e.Graphics.DrawSquare(new Point(10, 10), 20, new Pen(Brushes.Blue));
```